# Get all months and years in a range

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am writing a django application where I have records stored on the basis of datetimefield.

```
        first_record = MyModel.objects.filter().order_by('-added').first()
        first_record = (first_record.added.month, first_record.added.year)
        last_record = MyModel.objects.filter().order_by('-added').first()
        last_record = (last_record.added.month, last_record.added.year)
```

Now I want to make a list of all months/year between the first record and last record. A rough idea is:

```
for i in range(first_record, last_record):
    # do something
```

Where the range function is supposed to give me a list to iterate over which looks like this:

```
[('01','2018'),('02','2018'),('03','2018'),....,('11','2020'),('12','2020')]
```

Any ideas how do I do that?

Also is `(last_record.added.month, last_record.added.year)` the right way to get a tuple containing month and year. Note that I want months in the format `01` instead of `1` for first month for example.

Comment: `01` is not a valid integer, do you mean you want the months and years as strings?

Comment: Ah yes, correct.

Answer (score 4):

I believe Django has a built-in function. You can do:

```py
>>> Entry.objects.dates('pub_date', 'month')
[datetime.date(2005, 2, 1), datetime.date(2005, 3, 1)]
>>> Entry.objects.dates('pub_date', 'week')
[datetime.date(2005, 2, 14), datetime.date(2005, 3, 14)]
```

Which, translated into your code, will be something like

```py
MyModel.objects.dates('added', 'month')
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#dates)

Comment: `MyModel.objects.dates('added', 'month')`, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using dateutil.relativedelta
Here is the code

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

result = []

today = datetime.date.today()
current = datetime.date(2010, 8, 1)    

while current <= today:
    result.append(current)
    current += relativedelta(months=1)
```

Know more abou in
https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/relativedelta.html